# Can you echo money_format() inside of ""?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the following

```
echo "The price is money_format('$%i', $price)"
```

but that actually echos

```
money_format('$%i', 9.99)
```

Is it possible to echo the money_format('$%i', $var_name) with in ""?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question that probably doesn't deserve to be downvoted, at least not without comment.  It shows what the person is trying, what happens, and what they expect to happen.  It's true that someone with a bit more experience could probably Google for *PHP string concatenation* and figure it out quickly, but let's make StackOverflow a place where inexperienced programmers can ask basic questions and not be flooded by downvotes.  `+1` from me.

Comment: Mike, Thank you VERY MUCH! I'm a High School Technology teacher and I've recently decided to start teaching php and MySQL to my students. THEY LOVE IT!!! but I'm still VERY new. Thanks for your comment here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the concatenation operator

```
echo "The price is " . money_format('$%i', $price);
```

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, your answer was EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. But you can concatenate the string literal and the string returned by `money_format` using the [string concatenation operator `.`](http://www.php.net/language.operators.string):

```
echo "The price is " . money_format('$%i', $price);
```

Or pass the values as separate arguments to `echo`:

```
echo "The price is ", money_format('$%i', $price);
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can not echo functions inside of strings

the only two things you can make are these:

```
echo " $var and an array field: {$arr["fieldA"]";
```

function calls always have to be concatenated using the . operator like so:

```
echo " the return value of the function is: ".someFunction();
```

Comment: You also need to concatenate magic constants, like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way:

```
echo money_format("The price is %i", $number);
```

would have the same result